# Getting Gmail User Inbox All Emails

Tags: android, gmail-api

I have problem with getting user inbox emails using Gmail API. 
Basically i have problem with authentication i don't know how to  authenticate before requesting for emails.

I have register my app in Google developer console and created outh2Client Id for my app. And enabled the Gmail Api for this app.

Here is my manifest permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

And this my build.gradle file

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client- 
    android:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-slides:v1-rev294- 
    1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.25.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev104- 
    1.25.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

This is my Try to get all messages

```
    String url="https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/
    mudassirktk41@gmail.com/messages";
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("respos",response);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Log.d("respos",error.toString());

        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "OAuth 533655669585-79ors38egmiuj4ct3afcsfcv08lhegh6.apps.googleusercontent.com");
            return headers;
        }


    };

    requestQueue.add(request);
```

My Code gives error "com.android.volley.AuthFailureError" all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You May use G Suite APIs for Android as stated [HERE](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/guides/android). And Your dependency :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-<API>-<VERSION>') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}
```